# pyautogui.displayMousePosition returns strange output

Tags: python-3.x

```py
>>> pyautogui.displayMousePosition
<function displayMousePosition at 0x044538E8>
```

I want the output to display the mouse's coordinates, not some funky stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the function, add () behind, else you make it a callback.

> pyautogui.displayMousePosition()

*Will display the mouse X and Y along with its current position pixel color.*

More info on parentheses [here](https://www.quora.com/In-lines-of-code-in-Python-what-do-empty-parenthesis-brackets-mean-for-example-lower) and [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-do-we-call-the-functions-without-parentheses-ie).